# Google Play Console API, возможно ли реализовать отчет в CRM системе по средствам API

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Коллеги, приветствую!

Передо мной стала задача - в CRM системе отображать информацию по приложениям размещены в Google Play, по средствам их API.

Если кратно описать, что нужно, я имею вот такой список, по сути, это дублирование статистики из Play Console. Отображать я хочу следующую информацию:

1. Кол-во всего установок.
2. Кол-во активных установок (те кто пользуются на данный момент)
3. Оценка приложения пользователями.
4. Кол-во удалений
5. Отчеты о сбоях
6. Отчет об установках по регионам.
7. Устройство

Я почитал https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/, не нашел информацию о том, что это можно получить по API. Возможно я был не достаточно внимателен..

Коллеги, если у вас есть опыт извлечения подобной информации, возможно вы сможете направить на путь.